# How to use ciscodump?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, tcpdump, pcap

In wireshark, there is this option called `Cisco remote capture: ciscodump`, which, from my understanding, should enable to do a tcpdump on a cisco router (for example) via SSH and get back the results directly in Wireshark.

I didn't find any doc, cisco-side, about how this would work. How can I use ciscodump for this purpose ?

Comment: What are you trying to get?  Traffic passes through a router and is easy to spot with a packet sniffer.  Router configuration is not traditional traffic and needs the router admin credential to export.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is at
[ciscodump(1) Manual Page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/ciscodump.html) :

> Ciscodump is an extcap tool that relies on Cisco EPC to allow a user
> to run a remote capture on a Cisco device in a SSH connection. It
> supports IOS, IOS-XE based device and ASA devices.
>
> The tool configures capture on the device, reads data and removes
> configuration from the device. Provided credentials must allow the
> tool to configure the device.

Note also :

> The application supports IOS version is 12.4 and higher. The IOS version supporting capture feature is 12.4(20)T and higher.

If this applies to your setup, you will need to find out by trying what
the tool really does.
Links inside the man-page will give more information.